# MySql getting specific lines from TEXT

Tags: mysql, text

Ok so what i wish to do is to get specific lines from TEXT without loading all the data from TEXT into memory.
So lets say i have 100k lines of text in TEXT and i wish to get lines 9000-9100 from there.
I can do it with files but is it possible with mysql as well?
Or is it better to use file for this?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051125/select-x-lines-starting-at-line-y

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible to address values in a column with type TEXT by line. (You can do it by BYTE with [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-functions.html))

So do it by file or use another structure to save it in the database... e.g. save each line in a separate row with line number .. than you can easily query your wanted lines

Comment: Ok thanks. Data is temporary so i think im going with file option.