# Select X lines starting at line Y

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select a specific range of lines from a LONGTEXT in mysql.

For example, say I have a LONGTEXT column named `log_data` with the following text in it:

```
INFO this is the first line
INFO this is the second line
INFO this is the third line
INFO this is the fourth line
INFO this is the fifth line
```

I want to be able to select line 2-4 inclusive (but these values may change, some times i might want to select from line 15-26 in a 45 line long entry, etc).

Something like

```sql
select LINES(log_data, 2, 4) as log_data from logs where id = 7;
```

Should result in

```
INFO this is the second line
INFO this is the third line
INFO this is the fourth line
```

> Note: Lines are always delimited with `\n` and never `\r\n`.

I know i can select lines 0 to X using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, but that doesn't let me select the starting line as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we provide negative ***count*** in the [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function, it will count from the right to left, and fetch us the substring to the right of the delimiter.

So, with some maths, in order to get second (2) to fourth (4) line:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(log_data, '\n', 4), 
      '\n',
      -(4 - 2 + 1)
      )
```

Similarly, for lines 15 - 26 it will be:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(log_data, '\n', 26), 
      '\n',
      -(26 - 15 + 1)
      )
```

General formula for a **p** line to **q** line would be:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(log_data, '\n', q), 
      '\n',
      -(q - p + 1)
      )
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I need it to be inclusive. So i assume that means you would just change it to `-(q + 1 - p)`?

Comment: @NathanF. yes you are right ! I have rectified the answer as well

Comment: I don't think it is. `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n", '\n', 4), '\n', -(4 - 2)) as line_2_to_4` returns `3\n4`

Comment: Changing it to `-(4 + 1 - 2)` returns `2\n3\n4`